# Is doing a course and pursuing a career in Algorithmic Trading halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, profession

I want to do a course in  Algorithmic Trading.

The course itself does not talk about interest (Riba), but the applications of Algorithmic Trading may consider Riba as one of the factors.

Is it halal or haram?

Answer (score 1):

Algorithmic trading involves running high speed trades of complex derivative products. It also includes either speed trades of simple equities, or offline trades of complex products. The Former of these does not have anything haram. As the products become more complex, they tend to encompass all variants of equity/debt/forex, and very difficult to abstain from particular types.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be haram or at least doubtful in case that it is considered as a related program with the issue of Riba (interest) as you yourself mentioned that "the applications of Algorithmic Trading may consider Riba as one of the factors.". Since as probably you are aware, there are some verse in the holy Quran that mention the Hormah (being haram) of Riba and termed it as a very awful sin.